# How can I properly call functions within Enum.map?

Tags: elixir

I am trying to convert a string timestamp into unix time, however, I run into the following error:

```
(CompileError) nested captures via & are not allowed: &(NativeDateTime.diff(&1, ~N[1970-01-01 00:00:00]))
```

I am unfamiliar with how & functions in Elixir. The code fragment that I am trying to fix is:

```
|> Enum.map(fn 
  [user_id, state, timestamp] -> 
    unix = &NativeDateTime.from_iso8601(&1, timestamp) 
    |> &NativeDateTime.diff(&1,~N[1970-01-01 00:00:00])
```

Comment: Please also show us the format of the timestamp you are trying to parse. There is no `NativeDateTime` module, I think you mean `NaiveDateTime` - but it's better to use regular `DateTime` if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to try to define extra anonymous functions inside the `fn end` block - you can just use the arguments with regular function calls.

This works for me:

```elixir
[[nil, nil, "2022-05-24T19:00:30.510232Z"]]
|> Enum.map(fn [_user_id, _state, timestamp] ->
  {:ok, datetime, 0} = DateTime.from_iso8601(timestamp)
  DateTime.to_unix(datetime)
end)
```

Output:

```elixir
[1653418830]
```

Comment: This worked for me, thank you! I didn't realize I had also misspelled the module!